# Can I add a dictionary as a class attribute in Python?

Tags: python, class

I'm working on a DND project that completely creates a character for you. I want to make it so if an ability score is a certain number or within a certain range of numbers, the program will adjust the ability score.

```
def __init__(self, name, race, sub_race, char_class, size='Small', speed=0, strength=0, dexterity=0, constitution=0,
                 intelligence=0, wisdom=0, charisma=0):
        self.name = name
        self.race = race
        self.sub_race = sub_race
        self.char_class = char_class
        self.size = size
        self.speed = speed
        self.strength = strength
        self.dexterity = dexterity
        self.constitution = constitution
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.wisdom = wisdom
        self.charisma = charisma
```

I'd like to make it so the abilities (speed, strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence, wisdom, charisma) are in a dictionary within the class. This way I can update each individual ability score.

```
    def adjust_scores(self):
        if (self.speed or self.strength or self.dexterity or self.constitution or self.intelligence or self.wisdom or
            self.charisma) == 1:
```

Is there a way to make these scores into a dictionary and possibly iterate through each key/value pair and update their values?

Comment: `if (self.speed or self.strength or self.dexterity or self.constitution or self.intelligence or self.wisdom or self.charisma) == 1:` [does not do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/364696).

Comment: How would a dictionary help?  The posted code is fully able to adjust individual scores.

Comment: The `== 1` part of the condition is wrong.  You need to use `x == 1 or y == 1 or z == 1`.

Comment: If you want  those variables to be a dictionary, then ... make them a dictionary.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually quite simple. You can store a dictionary instead of attributes, like you are asking in the question, as shown below:

```
def __init__(self, name, race, sub_race, char_class, size='Small', speed=0, strength=0, dexterity=0, constitution=0,
                 intelligence=0, wisdom=0, charisma=0):
        self.attributes = {}
        self.attributes['name'] = name
        self.attributes['race'] = race
        self.attributes['sub_race'] = sub_race
        self.attributes['char_class'] = char_class
        self.attributes['size'] = size
        self.attributes['speed'] = speed
        self.attributes['strength'] = strength
        self.attributes['dexterity'] = dexterity
        self.attributes['constitution'] = constitution
        self.attributes['intelligence'] = intelligence
        self.attributes['wisdom'] = wisdom
        self.attributes['charisma'] = charisma
```

If you want to retain your specific attributes as well as the dictionary, you can have the best of both worlds by having the constructor be:

```
def __init__(self, name, race, sub_race, char_class, size='Small', speed=0, strength=0, dexterity=0, constitution=0,
                 intelligence=0, wisdom=0, charisma=0):
        self.attributes = {}
        self.attributes['name'] = name
        self.attributes['race'] = race
        self.attributes['sub_race'] = sub_race
        self.attributes['char_class'] = char_class
        self.attributes['size'] = size
        self.attributes['speed'] = speed
        self.attributes['strength'] = strength
        self.attributes['dexterity'] = dexterity
        self.attributes['constitution'] = constitution
        self.attributes['intelligence'] = intelligence
        self.attributes['wisdom'] = wisdom
        self.attributes['charisma'] = charisma
        self.name = name
        self.race = race
        self.sub_race = sub_race
        self.char_class = char_class
        self.size = size
        self.speed = speed
        self.strength = strength
        self.dexterity = dexterity
        self.constitution = constitution
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.wisdom = wisdom
        self.charisma = charisma
```

and either:

1 - when changing one of them, change the other
2 - have a special setter function for each attribute, which also changes the dict. Ex:

```
def setName(self, newName):
    self.name = newName
    self.attributes['name'] = newName
```

Edit: Sorry for my incorrect remarks about setters previously. As pointed out in comments, setters and the second method are generally a bad practice in Python (this doesn't apply to other languages such as Java, with specifications such as `private`).

However, this is by no means stopping you from using that method. If I understand your use-case correctly, then you shouldn't be extremely nitpicky at conventions, etc.

Comment: Maintaining two independent copies of the same variable like this is very bad practice.

Comment: setters are also not common Python practice